# convert valid mysql query into Mathematica statement

Tags: mysql, wolfram-mathematica

I have a valid mysql query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*), c.description
FROM name_loc f
INNER JOIN countries       c ON f.fk_cnty_id  = c.id
INNER JOIN identifiers     i ON f.fk_ident_id = i.id
GROUP BY f.fk_cnty_id;
```

It returns:

```
+------+----------------+
| cnt  | description    |
+------+----------------+
| 1093 | AUSTRALIA      |
|  235 | BELGIUM        |
|  474 | BERMUDA        |
```

I need a statement that will allow me to plot a histogram where the vertical axis is the count, and the horizontal axis is the county.

I thought this would work:

```
totalCntLByCnty =   {#[[1, 2]], #[[2]]} & /@ SQLExecute[conn, "
SELECT  COUNT(*), c.description
FROM name_loc f
INNER JOIN countries       c ON f.fk_cnty_id  = c.id
INNER JOIN identifiers     i ON f.fk_ident_id = i.id  
GROUP BY f.fk_cnty_id
"]
```

I get this error:

```
Part::partd: Part specification {2,ANDORRA}[[1,2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

I then needed to plot the histogram. I have spent an hour on this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in the form of a list of many sublists with two elements each. Like this:

```
{{cnt1,description1},{cnt2,description2},...}
```

Your mapping construct, `/@ result` picks out each sublist and hands it to the anonymous function. So `#` in your anonymous function is a list `{cnt,description}`. So `#[[1]]` is cnt, and `#[[2]]` is description. But you're trying to retrieve `#[[1,2]]` which would be the second element of `cnt` if `cnt` was a list. But since it's not a list, you can't retrieve that element. It doesn't exist. You're looking for either `#[[1]]` or `#[[2]]` but never `#[[1,something]]` since that's not the kind of data that you have.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now (I think). I used:  {#[[1]], #[[2]] } & /@ SQLExecute[conn, ". I got: {{2, "ANDORRA"}, {33, "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES"}, {14, "ANGUILLA"}, {1, 
  "ARMENIA"}, {78, "ARGENTINA"}}. I then used BarChart@totalCntLByCnty and got a bar chart, so far this is what I need, now what command would I use to plot the name of the country under the bar? Do I need to create another posting to this website? In any case thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have version 9 you can use the `ChartLegends` option. For example: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/how-do-i-change-the-font-in-barchart-legend (this site is better for Mathematica questions btw)